# Trying to understand weird behavior in function?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I wrote this function:

```
 (T = (({#[[1]][x], #[[2]][y]} - {x, y}) & /@ 
 Tuples[{Ceiling, Floor}, 2]);
 (t = (Sqrt[Total[#^2]] & /@ T);
 k = 0; m = Max[t]; (k++; {If[# == m, k, u], k}) & /@ t
 ) /. {x -> #1, y -> #2}) & @@ {1.1, 2.4}
```

It outputs this:

```
{{4, 1}, {u, 2}, {u, 3}, {u, 4}}
```

The part of this function that does this is:

```
(k++; {If[# == m, k, u], k}) & /@ t
```

My doubt is: When `k` is inside the `If[]` it seems that Mathematica interprets as `k=4` every time. But when `k` is outside of the `If[]`, it works properly ie: Iterating `k` everytime. Why does this happens?

Comment: Remove the `/. {....}` from your last line to see what is happening: essentially, the `If` keeps the `k` unevaluated until after `k` has been incremented to `4`

Comment: @LukasLang If I do that, an error occurs.

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: @lericr It should output 1 instead of 4 in `{4, 1}`

Answer (score 6):

You've got a `Function`. Its body happens to be a convoluted compound expression. A `Function` holds its body unevaluated, because it needs to wait to have its slots filled with arguments. So, `T`, `t`, and `m` are not set at all until we apply the function. As soon as we apply it, the `{x -> #1, y -> #2}` bit gets the slots filled with 1.1 and 2.4, and now we're off to the races trying to evaluate our function. `Tuples[{Ceiling, Floor}, 2]` gets evaluated and then a function gets mapped over that. We end up with `T` now being set to some expression involving `Ceilings`, `Floors`, `x`s and `y`s. `t` then becomes set to the result of mapping a function over `T`, so basically adding `Plus` and `Sqrt` to the mix. Now `k` is set to 0, and `m` gets set to `Max[...the whole complicated thing that is t...]`. That `Max` expression doesn't evaluate to a number, because Mathematica doesn't have enough info to evaluate it, so it just sits there as is for awhile. Now the next function, the one involving `k++` and `If` gets mapped over `t`, which remember is still a big complicated expression. The result is a list of pairs. The second element of each pair is an actual number, because `k` had an actual value at those moments. The first element of each pair is still a big complicated expression. Now, finally, **finally**, we do the replacements for `x` and `y`. Each of those first elements to the pair now resolve to either `k` or `u` depending of the `If` condition. The first case was the only one where the condition was `True`, so it evaluated to `k`, and all the others to `u`. Now, `u` has no OwnValues, so it just remains as `u`, but `k` does have OwnValues, specifically the value `4` (because it was incremented 4 times during the earlier computation when the `If` got mapped over `t`). And there you have it.

If you could describe the general semantics you're trying to implement, I'm sure there is a simpler and more reliable way to do it.

**UPDATE**

Okay, it looks like you're trying to find the distances from a given point to the four nearest integer lattice points. Here is a start:

```
CornerDistances[pt : {_, _}] := 
  EuclideanDistance[pt, #] & /@ Tuples[Through[{Floor, Ceiling}[pt]]]
```

You can try with your point:

```
CornerDistances[{1.1, 2.4}]
```

`{0.412311, 0.608276, 0.984886, 1.08167}`

Now, that's not the same ordering you had, so you may need to permute those. Finding the Max is easy, but I'm not sure what final structure you're going for--I don't know what the `u` means.